Auth.js (next-auth) callback on successful login
Is there any auth.js (next-auth) callback that is called after successful login (OAUTH, Magic Link, Credentials)? It can be used for keeping history of login activities, etc.
Thanks

There is a signIn event that can be used perhaps? It is an event sent on a successful sign in you can implement your logic for logs etc. there. Look at implementing NextAuth


import NextAuth from "next-auth";
export const {
  auth,
  handlers: {
    GET,
    POST
  },
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  // your pages, callbacks, etc.
  events: {
    async signIn({
      user,
      account,
      profile,
      isNewUser
    }) {
      // your logic here

    }
  }
})



you can find the documentation here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events

Thank you @Alexandr, this solved the problem!

Glad I can help! Have fun developing @Romstar!
